# How can I check whether a string ends with ".csv" in C

Tags: c, string

How can I check whether a string ends with `.csv` in C?

I've tried using `strlen` without any success.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

How about:

```
char *dot = strrchr(str, '.');
if (dot && !strcmp(dot, ".csv"))
    /* ... */
```

Comment: this, however, will not work for cases where the string contains more than period (not likely, but certainly possible)

Comment: @kappamaki: This works because `strrchr` finds the right-most dot.

Comment: That still doesn't work, because you could have a `.` in your path, but not in the filename

Comment: @DanielStephens in that case .csv won't be the end of the filename, hence the condition fails.

Comment: Shouldn't be accepted answer. This will scan entire string if it doesn't have a `.`, while you really need to check last four chars.

Answer (score 30):

```
if(strlen(str) > 4 && !strcmp(str + strlen(str) - 4, ".csv"))
```

Comment: So, `".csv"` does not end with `".csv"`?

Comment: Usually a file `.whatever` is considered to have the name `.whatever` and no extension. So for his use-cases this makes more sense IMO.

Comment: ... agreed (assuming we are talking about file names).

Comment: `strlen`, possibly an expensive operation, gets called twice

Comment: Honestly, the string is most likely a filename/path, calling `strlen` on it isn't going to be expensive unless you do it for millions of files in a loop.

Comment: @undur_gongor `!strcmp(...)` means `strcmp(...) == 0`, which for this function indicates that the 2 strings are equal.

Comment: @trxgnyp1: You seem to have missed the first part of the condition.

Comment: @undur_gongor What? I am replying to "*So, '.csv' does not end with '.csv'?*"
I assume you say that because it's checking if `!strcmp(...)`, and although it looks like it's negating the string comparison, it's checking if both strings are equal.

Comment: @trxgnyp1: I said that because the code is checking for the string length to be more than 4 (which isn't true for ".csv").

Answer (score 11):

The simplest (and most general) form of ThiefMaster's code would be:

```
int string_ends_with(const char * str, const char * suffix)
{
  int str_len = strlen(str);
  int suffix_len = strlen(suffix);

  return 
    (str_len >= suffix_len) &&
    (0 == strcmp(str + (str_len-suffix_len), suffix));
}
```