# how to find the files with .done extension from a specific directory using c language

Tags: c

```
    int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
   char *dirFilename = "/home/sv5071184/sample";
DIR *directory = NULL;
directory = opendir (dirFilename);

          if(directory == NULL)
           return -1;
           struct dirent *dirp;
             while ((dirp = readdir (directory)) != NULL) {

                if(  ! (strcmp (dirp->d_name ,".done") == 0)  )
                 {
                    printf ("%s\n", dirp->d_name);
                 }
                }
    if(closedir(directory) < 0)
        return -1;
}
```

NOTE: i have updated the code . with this code am able to find all the files in a directory whereas i need to find only .done files

Comment: Linux does not separate file names into a name and an extension. What do you think `ent->d_name.extension` is supposed to do? If you want to find file names that end in `.txt`, you need to manually check for that.

Comment: `ent->d_name` is a string (`char*`).
You need to check if that string ends with ".done". See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10347689/how-can-i-check-whether-a-string-ends-with-csv-in-c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `char *strstr(const char *haystack, const char *needle);` give you the position of the substring 'needle' if exists. Then you just have to test if the substring is at the end of the file name.

EDIT:
If you want to keep your code as you did, in the while, change your if condition to:
`strstr(dirp->d_name, ".done")!=NULL`

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you can find the extension using `strrchr`:

```
#include <string.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char *dirFilename = "/home/sv5071184/sample";
    DIR *directory = NULL;
    directory = opendir (dirFilename);

    if(directory == NULL)
        return -1;
    struct dirent *dirp;
    while ((dirp = readdir (directory)) != NULL) {
        char *dot = strrchr(dirp->d_name, '.'); /* Find last '.', if there is one */
        if (dot && (strcmp(dot, ".done") == 0))
        {
            printf ("%s\n", dirp->d_name);
        }
    }
    if(closedir(directory) < 0)
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: @jongware Lol..I have tried using strstr function. Thanks klas :)

Answer (score 0):

Finding files that end in specific string (an extension) is very common thing to do with file names.

For the better or worse, under POSIX standard, file name is not separated into name and extension , and unfortunately C string library does not have a function that is like endsWith in Java or C#.

I think that you should write a simple utility function `ends_with(char*, char*)` that checks if one string ends with another and use it to check if `ends_with(ent->d_name, ".done")`.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dirent.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char *dirFilename = "/home/sv5071184/sample";
    DIR *directory = NULL;
    directory = opendir (dirFilename);


    if(directory == NULL)
        return -1;
    struct dirent *dirp;
    while ((dirp = readdir (directory)) != NULL) {

        if ( strstr(dirp->d_name , ".done" ))
        {
            printf( "found a .done file: %s\n", dirp->d_name );
        }
    }
    if(closedir(directory) < 0)
        return -1;

}
```

I have used this way and it is working.. thanks everyone

Comment: Please be aware that `strstr` will find `.done` even if it isn't in the end of the name, so it will match file names like `x.done.txt`.