# Using PTrace to dump files opened by a process

Tags: unix, process, trace, ptrace

I am already familiar and successfully dumped the files opened by a process using strace.
With that being said, strace performance is causing degradation for my software and I would like to implement a wrapper using c++ for my software, in a way that ptrace will collect and dump files opened by the software.

I have found guides on how to attach, and modify registries - but that doesn't really help with anything.

Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

On linux, you can access the list of all open files in `/proc/<pid>/fd`. This directory contains just a bunch of symlinks for each open file; using standard directory iteration, you can create a list of open files very easily, e.g. on the terminal:

```
ls -l /proc/$(pidof bash)/fd/
```

For creating a C/C++ wrapper, you can e.g. use the techniques described in this related question: [How to list files in a directory in a C program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4204666/how-to-list-files-in-a-directory-in-a-c-program)