# How to access new files every time when it is added to the directory?

Tags: c, search, inotify

I have a directory by the name of **Container** which contains the demo.txt file. I am monitoring this **Container** directory and accessing this demo.txt file but if I copied a new file and tried to access it, I will also have to change the pathname/filename.

I want to automate this process. It means if the new file is added to the **Container** directory then it should check it automatically without having to give the **filename** every time. Because so many files are continuously adding every time.

**Is it possible this way?**

```
int main(){
    if(access("home/Container/demo.txt", F_OK ) != -1){
        printf("This file already exists in Container");
    }
    else{
        printf("This file does not exist");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to list files in a directory in a C program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4204666/how-to-list-files-in-a-directory-in-a-c-program)

Comment: This question boils down to this: you require a way to list files in a directory, and then you will be able to check when this changes. See this related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4204666/how-to-list-files-in-a-directory-in-a-c-program/17683417

Comment: How do you know what files are "new" when this process starts after it's been down for a while?  Using the filesystem as a message queue like you're trying to do here is usually a really bad idea. You're trying to use a state-saving device as an event detector.