# How to loop through large amount of folder faster

Tags: python

I have to loop through a large number of folder at a given path (`My_Path`) (around 60 000).
Then in each folder in `My_Path`, I have to check if a file name contains a certain date.
I want to know if there is a faster way than looping one by one using the `os` library. (Around 1 hour)

```
My_Path:
-   Folder 1
              o File 1
              o File 2
              o File 3
              o …
-   Folder 2
-   Folder 3
-   …
-   Folder 60 000
```

```py
import os
My_Path = r'\\...\...\...\...'
mylist2 = os.listdir(path)  # give a list of 60000 element
for folder in mylist2:
    mylist = os.listdir(My_Path + folder)  # give the list of all files in each folder
    for file in mylist:
        Check_Function(file)
```

The actual run takes around one hour and I want to know if there is an optimal solution.

Thanks !!

Comment: Python says that variable and function names should not be capitalized, please use `my_path` and `check_function` instead. Capital letters are reserved for class names.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10378046/1622937

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I iterate over files in a given directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10377998/how-can-i-iterate-over-files-in-a-given-directory)

Comment: Look at this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3162002/a-faster-way-of-directory-walking-instead-of-os-listdir

Answer (score 2):

Try `os.walk()`, might be faster:

```py
import os
My_Path = r'\\...\...\...\...'
for path, dirs, files in os.walk(My_Path): 
    for file in files:
        Check_Function(os.path.join(path, file))
```

If it is not, maybe it's your `Check_Function` eating up the cycles.

Comment: `walk` uses [`scandir`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0471/) on recent versions of Python, which (AFAICT) should be significantly faster on network drives under Windows

Answer (score 2):

As others already suggested you can obtain the list `lst` of all files as in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10378046/4819376). Then you can spin your function with multiprocessing.

```py
import multiprocessing as mp


def parallelize(fun, vec, cores):
    with mp.Pool(cores) as p:
        res = p.map(fun, vec)
    return res
```

and run

```py
res = parallelize(Check_Function, lst, mp.cpu_count()-1)
```

**Update**
Given that I don't think `Check_Function` is cpu bounded you can use even more cores.

Comment: @sam Please post an alternative answer of your own. This answer is not a community wiki answer and you shouldn't be making such serious changes.